# LLinux Device Driver interfacing

Tags: linux, drivers, devices

In device driver programming we are using following items:

1. Device driver code
2. Device file
3. Actual physical Hardware (till now not used in my coding)
4. User space application code

What I understood is device file is a intermediate bridge between device driver code and user application code. And device file is a temporary (like bidirectional pipe) buffer.

Can anybody clarify me whatever I understood is correct? Also explain me how above four listed things are communicated internally in kernel. Even tried from LDD3 book, but still I am not getting correct picture.

Comment: A device file is not a buffer, there's nothing really  "temporary" about it, and it doesn't _store_ anything.  When you write to a device file, that data is read by the kernel.  Incidentally, pipes also do not store any data; the reader reads what the writer writes essentially simultaneously.  Bidirectional pipes are typically called "sockets"  and they also don't store anything; I/O on them blocks reception.  Now let's see if I get corrected :P

Comment: @DanielFarrell, thanks for your reply. Still I want to know the exact communication happening between all above four listed things.